# Understanding だから...言ったろ

Tags: grammar

Here's the sentence:

> 「だから昨日も言ったろ、ボクもキミも怒られるタイプなんだって。」

だから as 'therefore' doesn't really work here so I'm going for "that's why".
However, I think 言ったろ means "did I not say". Putting it together I get

> That's why, did I not say yesterday that both you and me are the type who get told off.

But to make that work in English I need the comma or a pause for thought after "that's why" otherwise I get something non-grammatical.

Is the sentence grammatical in Japanese or is a pause needed like my English translation, or is my translation just wrong? Is there a better way to think about だから and 言ったろ?

Comment: 「だから言っただろ、～～って。」「だから言ったでしょう、～～って。」などは、よく "See, I told you so." という感じで使います。別に "gives a strong feeling that the speaker is annoyed" という感じじゃなく、もっと気軽な(または優しい)感じで使えます。

Comment: @choco Thanks. If you put that in an answer then I'll move the tick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

だから is sometimes used at the beginning of a sentence when the speaker is trying to emphasize something already said. I've heard it said to me in this usage as "だ〜か〜ら〜". I think you could translate this usage as "Like I said..."

To me, here the combination of だから plus 言ったろ（言っただろう） gives a strong feeling that the speaker is annoyed with the other person.

Answer (score 1):

“だから言ったじゃないの” is a popular phrase among today’s elderlies as it became a hit song with the same title, followed by “男の言葉に騙されて - (You are too stupid) to be cheated by a man's sweet talk,” which was sung by Keiko Matsuyama, and released in 1958.

In this case, だから does not necessarily mean “because” and “that why” as a conjunctive.

As @Choco advised, “だから” here works as the emphasis of the ensuing statement, “ボクもキミも怒られるタイプなんだって.”

I would translate the quote as:
“Remember, I told you yesterday that both of us are the type of getting easily scolded .”
“Well (you see), I told you yesterday that both of us are the type of always being reprimanded.”